# How to Set Column Name For Multiselect Column

Tags: jqgrid

I am using **multiselect: true** in jqgrid which gives by default checkbox in columnname also.

I want to have checkbox + Some Column name for that (For Example: Action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid creates additional internal columns if you use some options. `rownumbers: true` option creates column with the name `"rn"`, `multiselect: true` option add the column with the name `"cb"`, `subGrid: true` option add the column with the name `"subgrid"`. To overwrite the column header for the column one can use `setLabel` which works with any other standard columns. In the way you can set *any HTML fragment* in the column header.For example you can use

```js
$("#gridid").jqGrid("setLabel", "cb", "@");
```

to set `@` text in the column header of multiselect column.

Comment: But it will remove the checkbox and place the "@" as column name. But i want Both checkbox and "@" in column. Should i write something like $("#gridId").jqGrid("setLabel", "cb", "@ <input type='checkbox'>"); and then write some custom code for checkall and uncheckall

Comment: @Yogesh: If the id of your grid `gridId` then inside of `"cb"` column one have `<div>` with `id="jqgh_gridId_cb"`. So you can use for example `prependTo` or `appendTo` to add some information before or after the checkbox. Try `$("<span>a</span>").prependTo("#jqgh_gridId_cb"); $("<span>z</span>").appendTo("#jqgh_gridId_cb");`. You will see `a` before the checkbox and `z` after it. You have to use `multiselectWidth` to increase the width of multiselect column (`multiselectWidth: 40` for example).

Comment: yes this worked perfectly.
 
Thank you so much Oleg! :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ygandhi1990/QEzhr/527/`$("<span>Test <br /></span>").prependTo("#jqgh_list_cb");`

This working example as suggested by Oleg.